# Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^ne^{-x}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^ne^{-x}=0$$

So far I have said:

Let $\epsilon>0.$

Then $$|x^ne^{-x}-0|=|x^ne^{-x}| \leq |x^n...|$$

I'm not sure how to bound $e^{-x}$ though. How can I do this?

Comment: L'Hopital's Rule can be used here.

Comment: $e^{-x} < 1$ for all $x > 0$...

Comment: Yes, your solution is basically correct, but you can make some fine adjustments: Observe that $(n+1)!$ is merely a constant (for example), pick $c$  and that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{c}{x} = c* \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = c*0 = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For $x>0$ $x^ne^{-x}={{x^n}\over e^x}$= ${{x^n}\over{\sum_m{x^m\over m!}}}$ $\leq $ ${x^n\over{{x^{n+1}\over{(n+1)!}}}}$

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to prove it by definition if you don't have to.

Since $n$ is a fixed number in this limit we can apply L' Hospital rule n times.

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} x^ne^{-x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{x^n}{e^{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{n!}{e^x}=0
$$

Even though here it wasn't necessary note that since $x\rightarrow +\infty$ we can observe $x\ge n_0 , n_0\in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

Given that $n \in \Bbb{N}$, by applying consecutively ($n$-times) L'Hospital's rule we have
$$\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{(x^n)'}}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(e^x)'}=\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{(nx^{n-1})'}}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(e^x)'}=\cdots=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$ 
but $$\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{n!}}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(e^x)'}=0$$ 
so the initial limit is equal to $0$.

Answer (score -1):

Do expansion of e^x. You may know it. Then use either Mathematical Induction or Reasoning to prove that limit equals 0 ... but I prefer to apply L'Hospital's Rule, because that will prevent you from doing Hard Reasoning.

Comment: If you still think that mine solution does not help to bound e^-x; then my information may help you in the sense that Mathematical Reasoning and Reasoning does provide a perfect proof to any Statement. Additionally, you can never guess (straight-forwardly) what's really happening between e^-x and x^n (or the other-way-round) when x tends to infinity.

Comment: Finally, please and at last refer to the solution of MathematicanByMistake. Its Amazing. Good work-out.