# Solving an interesting limit without series expansion and l'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'd like to find a solution to this limit without using series expansion.

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2+x+1}-\dfrac{\ln(e^x+x)\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{x}\right)
$$

**My thoughts:**

As $\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2+x+1}$ is an increasing function, it tends to infinity as $x\to\infty$.

As $\ln(e^x+x)\sqrt{x^2+x+1}$ is a product of two increasing functions, it is an increasing function which grows faster than $x$ in the denominator.

As both minuend and subtrahend tend to infinity as $x\to\infty$, this limit has a form $\infty - \infty$.

To clarify the siuation, this needs some algebraic manipulation. This is what I came up with:

$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2+x+1}-\dfrac{\ln(e^x+x)\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{x} &=
x\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{x^3}}-\dfrac{x\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}\ln(e^x+x)}{x} \\
&= x\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{x^3}}-\ln(e^x+x)\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}
\end{align*}$$

Another $\infty - \infty$, even though without outer fraction. This is where I got stuck.

How to find that limit?

Comment: You can bound them a bit better and squeeze.  Probably also need $x^ne^{-x}\to 0$ which may be a bit difficult/tedious if you don't allow series or L'Hopitals and cannot quote this (similarly for log).

Comment: that limit equal 1/6

Comment: @user10354138 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746213/) the $x^ne^{-x}\to 0$ had already been discussed. Still, I don't get how do I bound it. I know how to arrive to the form, however: $\ln(e^x+x)=\ln\left(e^x\left(1+\dfrac{x}{e^x}\right)\right)=x+\ln\left(1+\dfrac{x}{e^x}\right)$.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik It's $-1/6$, I was asking about how to come up to the answer, not what the answer is :)

Comment: Did you try $\frac{1}{t}=x$? You can then use Taylor, to get $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^\frac{1}{3}=1+\frac{1}{3}x+O(t)$ and $(1+x+x^2)^\frac{1}{2}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+O(t)$, then the limit is now; $$L=\lim_{t \to 0+}\left[\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+t+t^2+t^3}}{t}-\frac{\sqrt{1+t+t^2}}{t} t\ln \left(\frac{1}{t}+e^{\frac{1}{t}}\right)\right]\\
$$ and  $L=\frac{-1}{6}$ after substituting the approximations. Note that the natural log term tends to unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substitution $x=1/h$ so that $h\to 0^+$ and the expression under limit changes to $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+h+h^2+h^3}}{h}-\sqrt {1+h+h^2}\log((1/h)+e^{1/h})$$ Now take $e^{1/h}$ out of the argument of logarithm to get $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+h+h^2+h^3}-1}{h}-\frac{\sqrt{1+h+h^2}-1}{h}-\sqrt{1+h+h^2}\log(1+(1/h)e^{-1/h})$$ First term tends to $1/3$, second term tends to $1/2$ and third term tends to $0$ so that the desired limit is $-1/6$.